# Why the dialog don't works in parallel with a thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, dialog

Why the dialog don't works in parallel with a thread?
Using this code, the activity freeze and the progress dialog don't show...
I need to show the progress dialog during the download of files...

in the onCreate:

```
pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.setTitle(null);
        pDialog.setMessage(getString(R.string.loading));
```

in the download method:

```
startReader = true;
        pDialog.show();
        new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run(){
                for(int i = 1; i <= Integer.parseInt(pages); i++){
                    try{
                        if(!isCached(code,i)){
                            try{
                                CODE TO DOWNLOAD THE FILE;
                                Log.d(TAG, "File downloaded: /"+ code + "/" + "pg" + i + ".rsc");
                            }catch(IOException e){
                                runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                                    public void run(){
                                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getString(R.string.reader_errinternetcon), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                });
                            }
                        }                       
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                            public void run(){
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                        startReader = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                if(startReader){
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                        public void run(){
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ReaderActivity.class);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                            intent.putExtra("Pages", pages);
                            intent.putExtra("Code", code);
                            getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }).start();
        pDialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Thread.start()` starts the thread but does not wait for it to finish. You dismiss your dialog immediately afterwards. That's why you don't see the progress dialog.

I suggest you make your background thread an `AsyncTask`. Set up your progress dialog in `onPreExecute()`, do your background thread processing in `doInBackground()` and do UI thread post-processing such as dismissing progress dialogs in `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: @FelipePorgeXavier please upvote laalto's answer and accept it, so he can get credit for assisting you !

Comment: ahhh - sorry forgot about that ... well keep at it - @last cnt you're at 11 :)) won't take long if you participate.